# fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported git push not working?

Tags: git, github, git-push, github-for-windows, git-http-backend

I have set the origin to my online Git Repository and there is nothing to commit

```
git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

but still I am getting this when I try to push my README.md,html, css, js and some images files

```
$ git push -u origin main
fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+protocol+https+is+not+supported

Answer (score 0):

Please type in

```bash
git remote -v
```

Try to add SSH instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I seriously was completely done with using git...